# Устанавливаю gnome-tweaks но его нету в списке приложений

Tags: linux, ubuntu

решил я преобразить свою ubuntu и установить gnome-tweaks
собственно процесс установки идет как обычно

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
Предлагаемые пакеты:
gnome-shell-extension-prefs | gnome-shell-extension-manager
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
gnome-tweaks
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 9 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/59,5 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 426 kB.
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета gnome-tweaks.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 219705 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/gnome-tweaks_42~beta-1ubuntu2_all.deb …
Распаковывается gnome-tweaks (42~beta-1ubuntu2) …
Настраивается пакет gnome-tweaks (42~beta-1ubuntu2) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) …
```

после этого открываю меню с приложениями, а gnome-tweaks там нету
помогите запустить-таки его!

Comment: а через терминал запускается `gnome-tweaks` ?

Answer (score 1):

Как узнать список файлов в пакете `gnome-tweaks`:

```
dpkg -L gnome-tweaks
```

У меня в Ubuntu 18.04 эта команда выводит вот какой список:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gnome-tweaks
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/gnome-tweak-tool
/usr/lib/gnome-tweak-tool/gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/__init__.py
   исходники на Python
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.tweaks.desktop
/usr/share/doc
   Документация
/usr/share/gnome-tweaks
/usr/share/gnome-tweaks/shell.css
/usr/share/gnome-tweaks/shell.ui
/usr/share/icons
   Иконки
/usr/share/locale
   Файлы локализации
/usr/share/metainfo
/usr/share/metainfo/org.gnome.tweaks.appdata.xml
```

Если `gnome-tweaks` отсутствует в меню приложений, то скорее всего отсутствует файл `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.tweaks.desktop`. Скачайте любую версию этого пакета и извлеките из него файл `desktop`, потом ручками добавьте в `/usr/share/applications`

Answer (score 1):

Когда открываете список приложений, введите в поисковую строку gnome-tweaks, и запустите его один раз. После одного запуска, когда будете открывать список приложений его будет видно, и поиском пользоваться больше не придется.

Answer (score 0):

он сейчас называется "Доп. настройки GNOME" в меню `Утилиты`, а перед этим в меню `Системные`→`Настройки`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]